# Load style from file using external component

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have problems with external components when I load a style file inside a `TStyleBook`.

I can edit the default style, or create new one for external component using a `TStyleBook`. If the component is directly inside a `TForm` it works.

For external reason, I can't do that and I need to load the `TStyleBook` from a `.style` file:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StyleBook1.LoadFromFile('C:\test.style');
end;
```

If it contains an external component (not an internal delphi component like `TLabel`, `TPanel`, ..), I got an error

My style file content:

```
object TStyleContainer
  object TLayout
    StyleName = 'htlayout'
    Align = Client
    object THtLabel
      Align = Client
      Text = 'aaaa'
    end
  end
end
```

The error raises in this function (from `System.Classes`):

```
function TReader.FindComponentClass(const ClassName: string): TComponentClass;
```

Where `ClassName = 'THtLabel'`, if the component is on the `TForm` it's ok, but if it come from a style file I got a `ClassNotFound`.

`GetFieldClassTable(ClassType)` return nil when `ClassType` is a `TStyleContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the solution is to register the class:

```
initialization
 RegisterFmxClasses([THtLabel]);
end.
```